# using the same name for event and method of class

Tags: vb.net, events, overloading

am writing a class that has the same name for events and method, but visual studion won't allow me

The event

```
public event Close()
```

the method

```
Public Sub Close()

End Sub
```

how can i do this, i don't want to use different names

thanks

Comment: vb6 does this alot, take for example the winsock control, it has an event `close` and a method `Close`. why should we be restricted? The .net compiler can't figure this out?

Comment: vb6 events use a different interface, preventing the ambiguity.  That's not the way .NET works.  A good event name would be Closing or Closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft Framework Design Guidelines specifies something along the lines of the following as best practice (these are from our internal document but derived from the former mentioned guidelines to which I will find a link):

> - Do name events with a verb or a verb phrase.
> - Do give event names a concept of before and after, using the present and past tense
>     (gerunds.)
>
>   - For example, a close event that is raised before a window is closed would be called > `Closing` and one that is raised after the window is closed would be called `Closed`.
> - Do not use `Before` or `After` prefixes or suffixes to indicate pre and post events.
> - Do name event handlers (delegates used as types of events) with the `EventHandler` suffix.
> - Do use two parameters named `sender` and `e` in event handler signatures.
>
>   - The sender parameter should be of type `Object`, and the `e` parameter should be an instance of or inherit from `EventArgs`.
> - Do name event argument classes with the `EventArgs` suffix.
> - Do name event handler method with On.
>
>   - For example, a method that handles a `Closing` event should be named `OnClosing`.

Update: [Relevant Microsoft Design Guidelines Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the .NET compiler doesn't allow this kind of overloading. 
Try this instead:

```
public event OnClose()

Public Sub Close()
    ' implementation goes here
End Sub
```

Comment: Though not the law, Microsoft practice this the other way around (see my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler allowed this then it would probably allow instance variables and delegates to have the same name, too. Imagine this (nonsensical) code:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public XYZ As String
    Public Event XYZ(ByVal X As XYZ)
    Public Delegate Sub XYZ()
    Public Sub XYZ()
        RaiseEvent XYZ(AddressOf XYZ)
    End Sub
End Class
```